# get id's of multiple rows in one cell in r data.table

Tags: r, data.table, unique, long-format-data

I have a data.table in long format:

```
dt <- data.table(id=1:3, Q1=c(1,2,1), Q2=c(3,1,3), Q3=c("a","b","a"), Q4=c("d","c","d"))
dt
   id Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
1:  1  1  3  a  d
2:  2  2  1  b  c
3:  3  1  3  a  d
```

If I do

```
unique(dt[,Q1:Q4])
   Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
1:  1  3  a  d
2:  2  1  b  c
```

I get unique rows, but I lose the id's information.
I would want to keep these in one row only, like this:

```
    id Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
1: 1,3  1  3  a  d
2:   2  2  1  b  c
```

How could I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dt[, .(id = paste0(id, collapse = ";")), by = .(Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)]
#    Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4  id
# 1:  1  3  a  d 1;3
# 2:  2  1  b  c   2
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a list-column for this, in case you ever want to have distinct `id`s again. This is not very different from Wimpel's answer, it's just replacing `paste` with `list`, but it's different enough of a *concept* to break out:

```r
dt2 <- dt[, .(id = list(id)), by = .(Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4)]
dt2
#       Q1    Q2     Q3     Q4     id
#    <num> <num> <char> <char> <list>
# 1:     1     3      a      d    1,3
# 2:     2     1      b      c      2
```

With this, if you ever need to look for "membership", you can still use `%in%` (though you'd need to `lapply` or similar):

```r
dt2[ sapply(id, `%in%`, x = 1), ]
#       Q1    Q2     Q3     Q4     id
#    <num> <num> <char> <char> <list>
# 1:     1     3      a      d    1,3
```

Otherwise, if you use something like `toString` or `paste`, you'd need to work with regexes to try to find membership.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans! I accepted @Wimpel answer because it is quite easy and solves my problem, but it's good to know the potential of lists here.